# Is MemoryStream.WriteTo an Asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, memorystream

I wonder if MemoryStream.WriteTo is an asynchronous method ?

i am using it like this in my asynchronous Socket Server

```
public void Send(byte[] buffer)
{
    if (buffer == null)
        return;

    using (var s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        if (SslStream != null) s.WriteTo(SslStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't.

Comment: So how could i send data asynchronously because i can't use SslStream.WriteAsync. for the reason it tells me BeginWrite cannot be called while another write method is pending

Comment: Why not? That seems somewhat limiting, given your requirements. Perhaps it would be better to find out why you're seeing that problem. Don't give up on the right way just because you can't get it working.

Comment: My ssl Server will be sending data to alot of users at the same time thats why i want an asynchronous send method

Comment: I suggest opening a different question to solve your original issue: "BeginWrite cannot be called while another write method is pending "

Comment: @DanielEugen You really don't want multiple writers to a single network stream. At the very least, you'll need to employ some synchronization to ensure that only one write request is pending at any time. But as spender said, that would be a new question :)